# Migrate a physical Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop to WSLg in Windows 11 by mounting the system SSD

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, migration

I have a existing physical Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop system running on a SSD with ext4 as the file system.

I mounted the SSD into the WSLg Ubuntu in Windows 11.

To keep the same experience as much as possible, I want to use the mounted SSD as the main system disk to replace the default installation of Ubuntu in WSLg.

Is that possible?

I have tried chroot into the SSD in WSLg and successfully ran some CLI software. But it failed to launch all those GUI applications like Jetbrains IDEs.

What's more, after migration, I wish I could still boot into the same physical Ubuntu system using the same SSD when needed.

Comment: Short answer: No, not possible or even desirable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Just curious, what makes you so sure?  You may be right, but heck, I'm a pessimist/realist by nature and I can see *some* hope of this working.  I can at least see the *possibility* of solving the `chroot` issue by mapping the Interop socket.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks! Could you please provide more informations about the mapping the Interop socket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure (yet) that there's a way to use the drive as a WSL instance itself, I do think we can get the chroot method working, at least to some degree.

Here's the setup that I used:

- [Ubuntu Base 21.10 rootfs image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/21.10/release/) extracted (as sudo) to `$HOME/chroot/Ubuntu21.10`.
- For testing, after the below configuration was completed, `apt install xterm`
- For anyone attempting this with an actual rootfs, note that you should untar with the `xattrs` option, e.g.:

  ```
  # Download Ubuntu Base rootfs into the current directory, then:
  mkdir Ubuntu21.10
  cd !$
  sudo tar -xvz --xattrs -f ../ubuntu-base-21.10-base-amd64.tar.gz
  ```

Off the top of my head, I can't see a reason that this wouldn't be a semi-accurate representation of an existing SSD that you've been able to mount into a directory inside of a WSL/Ubuntu instance.  However, I'm sure there will be items I didn't anticipate from your configuration.  Let me know via comment here (plus possibly via new question if warranted) if you run into issues.

##### What's working

- Networking
- Running Windows `.exe`s from within the chroot (including GUI apps)
- Running Linux GUI apps from within the chroot (requires, of course, Windows 11)

##### What's known not to work

- Cannot mount Windows drives from within the chroot (e.g. `mount -t drvfs ...`).  This is likely due to the fact that I haven't yet been able to find a way to mount the special WSL `drivers` and `lib` filesystems.  Everything else works here via either a `mount` of the actual filesystem into the chroot path or via a `mount --bind` ("bind mount") of an existing path from WSL into the chroot path.
- The Windows path is not populated into that of the chroot (which WSL normally does via `/init`.  This means that you will have to use the fully-qualified path to run any `.exe`s.  Populating the path isn't all that difficult to script, but this answer is long enough as it is, so I'll leave the as an exercise to the reader (or a separate question).

##### Not Tested

- Audio:  If it doesn't work, then it's probably just a matter of finding the right environment variables, or perhaps one more socket to mount if needed.
- VSCode:  *May* have issues due to "default user" expectation on VSCode's part)
- Lots of other stuff

##### One-time prep

There are a few tasks to prep the chroot filesystem for the first time.

- From inside WSL (not in the chroot), create mountpoints and copy over some WSL items:

  ```
  cd <your_chroot_mountpoint_root>
  # Create mount points
  sudo mkdir mnt/c
  sudo mkdir run/WSL
  sudo mkdir mnt/wslg
  sudo mkdir mnt/wsl
  sudo mkdir -p usr/lib/wsl/drivers usr/lib/wsl/lib

  # Copy WSL generated config files - Currently doesn't work, but there for future reference/use
  # sudo cp /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ld.wsl.conf etc/ld.so.conf.d

  # Delete existing resolv.conf and use the one generated by WSL
  sudo rm etc/resolv.conf
  sudo ln -rs mnt/wsl/resolv.conf etc/

  # Delete existing X socket (if exists) and use the one generated by WSL
  [ -S tmp/.X11-unix ] && sudo rm tmp/.X11-unix
  [ -f tmp/.X11-unix ] && sudo rm tmp/.X11-unix
  [ -L tmp/.X11-unix ] && sudo rm tmp/.X11-unix
  sudo ln -rs mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/ tmp/.X11-unix

  # Set up fstab for recurring mount points.

  # (0) Make sure you are in the root of the chroot
  #     (the mounted drive, in your case) before
  #     running each command.
  # (A) I suggest running these lines one-by-one to make sure
  #     they work since ...
  # (B) They are not idempotent
  # (C) Check /etc/fstab after each one.  They should be 
  # pointing to the appropriate directory in your chroot

  # Set up bind mounts for the WSL generated sockets and files:
  sudo sh -c 'echo "/mnt/wsl $PWD/mnt/wsl none bind 0 0" >> /etc/fstab'
  sudo sh -c 'echo "/mnt/wslg $PWD/mnt/wslg none bind 0 0" >> /etc/fstab'
  #sudo sh -c 'echo "/run/WSL $PWD/run/WSL none bind 0 0" >> /etc/fstab' # Currently causes issues

  # Create fstab entries for the necessary filesystems.  For
  # the most part, we do this by finding the entry in 
  # /etc/mtab that WSL generated, copying that over to
  # /etc/fstab, and substituting the chroot path.

  sudo sh -c "grep '^drvfs[[:space:]]\+/mnt/c\W' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/mnt/c\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"
  sudo sh -c "grep '^none[[:space:]]\+/dev[[:space:]]' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/dev\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"
  sudo sh -c "grep '^proc[[:space:]]\+/proc[[:space:]]' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/proc\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"
  sudo sh -c "grep '^devpts[[:space:]]\+/dev/pts[[:space:]]' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/dev/pts\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"
  sudo sh -c "grep '^sysfs[[:space:]]\+/sys[[:space:]]' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/sys\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"
  sudo sh -c "grep '^binfmt_misc[[:space:]]\+/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc[[:space:]]' /etc/mtab | sed \"s-\(/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc\)-${PWD}\1-\" >> /etc/fstab"

  # Mount these newly added entries in `/etc/fstab`.  Only needed once -- From here on out, they will automount when you restart the WSL instance:
  sudo mount -a
  ```
- There's one thing that doesn't quite work here.  We can't seem to bind mount `/run/WSL` via `/etc/fstab`.  I believe this is due to a timing issue -- WSL probably hasn't completed mounting the original `/run/WSL`, so we can't yet bind mount it.  Attempting to do so will result in an error at WSL start-up.  This error is not fatal.

  You have several options.  You can either:
  * Run the commented-out line above to generate the fstab entry, deal with the error, and then run `sudo mount -a` after you restart WSL (or add it to a startup file)
  * Just run `sudo mount --bind /run/WSL/ $PWD/run/WSL/` (from inside the chroot root directory) after a WSL restart (Or add it to a startup file).

Starting the chroot:

```
sudo chroot $PWD env WSL_INTEROP="$WSL_INTEROP" DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" WAYLAND_DISPLAY="$WAYLAND_DISPLAY" XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" /usr/bin/bash
```

This populates the environment with the necessary environment variables before starting the shell.  There may be additional variables that you want to map, and that's easy enough.

I recommend an `apt update` to start.  This will at least tell you if DNS resolution is working.  If not, check the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink.

Other startup alternatives include creating a user with the same name as in your WSL instance and then:

```
sudo chroot $PWD env WSL_INTEROP="$WSL_INTEROP" DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" WAYLAND_DISPLAY="$WAYLAND_DISPLAY" XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" runuser -u $USER /usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: did you manage to get audio working?

Comment: it is not necessary to be on windows 11 to get the above working. windows 10 build version 10.0.19045.2311 or above is sufficient to mount a linux disk on a different drive. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7940#issuecomment-1320365216

Comment: @JoannMorris I honestly haven't looked at it since the question was asked a while back. But with what I know now, I think I can get it to work.  It might be a few days before I get a chance to try it out, though.  Check back in regularly, and I'll Ping you when I update it.

Comment: @JoannMorris and yes, it's now possible on Windows 10 as well.  I just have 100's of answers here, so I typically only spot the ones that need updating when there's new activity on it. ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDroids I got audio working. set the following variables 

PULSE_SERVER="/mnt/wslg/PulseServer"

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$chroot_id" 


#where chroot_id is the id of the user within linux  

also mount
bindfs --map=$wsl_id/$chroot_id:@$wsl_group/@$chroot_group /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir $disk/run/user/$chroot_id

I mounted the following for good measure
mount --bind /run/systemd/ $disk/run/systemd
mount --bind /run/dbus/ $disk/run/dbus
mount --bind /run/WSL/ $disk/run/WSL/

Comment: @JoannMorris Excellent!  You should add that as a supplementary answer.

Answer (score 1):

extension of @NotTheDr01ds answer.
set the following variable to get audio working within chroot environment.

```
PULSE_SERVER="/mnt/wslg/PulseServer"
```